# Android socket file transfer between two android phones

Tags: android, file-io

So im trying to create an android program that transfers a file from one android phone to another. I put the send and receive methods to be called when the send button is clicked, but it doesnt seem to send the file to the destination. (currently testing it with one phone)
Below is the code: any help would be appreciated

```
 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream; 


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("34");
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
        System.out.println("36");
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowse))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        System.out.println("40");
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                                SELECT_PICTURE);
                        System.out.println("47");
                    }
                });
        ;
        System.out.println("51");
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        final TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Socket sock;
                try {
                    sock = new Socket("10.0.0.16", 8080); //IP
                    System.out.println("Connecting...");

                     // sendfile
                          File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath); 
                          byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                          bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                          OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
                          System.out.println("Sending...");
                          os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                          os.flush();

                        sock.close();

                        int filesize=65383; // filesize temporary hardcoded

                        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        int bytesRead;
                        int current = 0;

                        // create socket
                        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(8080);
                        while (true) {
                          System.out.println("Waiting...");

                          Socket sock2 = servsock.accept();
                          System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock2);

                       // receive file
                            byte [] mybytearray2  = new byte [filesize];
                            InputStream is = sock2.getInputStream();
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Screenshots/IMG-20130112-WA0011.jpeg"); // destination path and name of file
                            //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Screenshots/");
                            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray2,0,mybytearray2.length);
                            current = bytesRead;


                            do {
                               bytesRead =
                                  is.read(mybytearray2, current, (mybytearray2.length-current));
                               if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                            } while(bytesRead > -1);

                            bos.write(mybytearray2, 0 , current);
                            bos.flush();
                            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            System.out.println(end-start);
                            bos.close();



                          sock2.close();
                        }

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
                path.setText("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Path: " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bBrowse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Files Available on  Your Phone to Send" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send Selected File" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"> </uses-permission>
```

Comment: Are you running those two sections on different phones or the same one?  If its the same one, it isn't going to work.  You're sending data to a socket when the listening socket doesn't exist yet-  the call to connect() on the base linux OS is going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think your app will be blocked on

```
sock = new Socket("10.0.0.16", 8080); //IP
System.out.println("Connecting...");
```

because the server hasn't been set up yet. Am I right? Has "Connecting..." been printed?